# How to restart phoenix automatically in-case of host reboot?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

As we can start phoenix server in detached mode as:

```
$ MIX_ENV=prod PORT=4000 elixir --detached -S mix phoenix.server
```

how would it be possible to restart phoenix in-case of crash or host reboot? what's the recommend way to do so?

**edit**

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-57-generic (buildd@brownie) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015
```

**edit2**

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

Comment: That's very OS specific. What OS are you using?

Comment: kindly see edit above

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is that? Try `cat /etc/lsb-release`.

Comment: `14.04` as in edit above

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ubuntu upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html). It allows you run scripts when Ubuntu boots.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to use [Monit](https://mmonit.com) as it will bring your phoenix app back to life even when whole Beam VM was crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need some monitoring service, like `upstart`, `monit`, `god`.
Or use Docker - e.g.

`docker run -d --restart=always ...`